# Parental Control for Internet?

Tags: safety, age-appropriate, video-games, play-time, computer

For a parent, how do we best control the content of the ENTIRE household's Internet in a **centralized** manner?

This settings of parent controls for individual network-based devices is **maddening** and often incomplete in terms of time-limit and content-limit.

Comment: I'm marking this as duplicate because this site is about _parenting_ but your question about household-wide Internet monitoring is basically a technical how-to question that's much better answered over at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Comment: How is this duplicate? This question is about a specific technical solution, not about the more general question what the right approach is.

Comment: @Torben: How is this different than asking for recommendations for a car seat? Are those off topic too?

Comment: Had I been able to add an answer, I'd recommend to configure one or two devices for unsupervised use, and to use all other devices under parental supervision. I wouldn't want my kids fooling around on my laptop and accidentaly deleting my tax data.

Comment: good call on that duplicate - I had forgotten we had that one. If the OP wants a technical content filtering solution, SU is definitely the place to ask.

Comment: @ATS - asking for a car seat recommendation is asking for a specific product and shopping questions are off topic.  The equivalent for this question is 'what will safely restrain my children in a car'.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want centralised control, get yourself a content filtering firewall in longer with your broadband router (or a broadband router with content filtering, which a lot have now)

Alternatively signing up to the content filtering service from your ISP will make it simple.

Personally, I'd recommend going the route of not censoring, but instead using the internet together with your children, education and awareness.